# Git push working GitKraken, failing due to permissions in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitkraken

I am able to pull/push to GitHub via GitKraken on my Windows 10 machine but when using VS Code on the same machine I get permission errors.

Any thoughts?

```
git remote --verbose
git.stage 1
git.stage.scmResources 1
git add -A -- e:\code\sportsman_cal\public_html\js\nowMe.js
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse QuickUpdate1
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name QuickUpdate1@{u}
git rev-list --left-right QuickUpdate1...refs/remotes/origin/QuickUpdate1
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
git remote --verbose
git show :public_html/js/nowMe.js
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse QuickUpdate1
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name QuickUpdate1@{u}
git rev-list --left-right QuickUpdate1...refs/remotes/origin/QuickUpdate1
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
git remote --verbose
git commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
git status -z -u
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse QuickUpdate1
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name QuickUpdate1@{u}
git rev-list --left-right QuickUpdate1...refs/remotes/origin/QuickUpdate1
git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
git remote --verbose
git config --get commit.template
git show :public_html/js/nowMe.js
git pull --tags origin QuickUpdate1
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Yes, some actual error messages and additional information would be lovely.

Comment: Updated with errors from VS Code. GitKraken pushes without any errors.

Comment: They probably have different home folders, which means that they would have different SSH keys for authentication. But that is just a guess since the only relevant information in the question is the error message.

Comment: If you're on Windows and using ssh, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72029153/308451 for a detailed explanation of what's going on, which may help you

Comment: The link that JBSnorro commented helped me (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72029153/9714002), even tho the exact symptoms weren't the same. I left a comment on that answer to describe my issue too